# Is the Mace of the Insolent comparable to the Blue Flame sword?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I've read on various forums that the Blue Flame Sword for sorcery casters can scale insanely well (innate magic damage, magic infusion, and crystal magic weapon). If done correctly, this can be the second best catalyst in the game. I've had a really hard time finding concrete info about the Mace of the Insolent. From what I've read, it won't do as well on a pure lightning/dark build because it scales both of them. The best info I could find was people saying they would test it and post results, and that was a month ago with no results posted. Can the Mace of the Insolent with a lightning infusion be a viable choice for a pure lightning caster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viable? Depends on what you mean by "viable". Spellcasting is very strong in Dark Souls 2, many bosses are much easier if you are a caster. PvE-wise, the Mace of the Insolent is a very good choice. Now, when it comes to PvP, there are several things we need to consider when you talk about viability.

First off, everything is viable in DaS2 PvP in the sense that you can use anything to beat anyone up so long as you have the skill (ladles OP). In comparison to Blue Flame, however, the Mace doesn't quite match up as a dual-function catalyst. The reason for this is fairly straightforward: Mace of the Insolent spreads itself too wide. Because it has to scale with both lightning *and* dark (because it acts as a catalyst for hexes and miracles), its damage and scaling for physical, lightning, and dark are all reduced in comparison to Blue Flame. Blue Flame is amazing simply because it only has to invest in physical and magic scaling. It's the classic D&D problem of MAD (Multiple Attribute Dependency).

In spite of these glaring weaknesses, the Mace can be a surprisingly useful tool to have in your arsenal. Mace of the Insolent has the all-important Strike damage type, unlike Blue Flame's Slash damage type. What makes Strike damage so great is that it typically deals more damage to heavily-armored opponents as heavy armor typically has lower Strike defense than it has Slash defense. So, your Mace of the Insolent will typically deal at least a bit more damage to the average Havelmage than a Blue Flame.

Now, to the last question: is Mace of the Insolent viable for a pure caster? Sadly, no. If you aren't going to be doing any attacking with it, you're better off using a Dragon Chime or really any other chime. The Mace's base lightning is so low in comparison, it's really not worth using it over any of your standard chimes.